# How is aperture handled when in live view mode?

Tags: aperture, camera-basics, live-view

When you are using the viewfinder, whatsoever the aperture value is, the lens will be in widest aperture until DOF-preview button pressed or half-shutter button.
But what about the aperture value when using Live view mode? Is it the value set by user in aperture or any other standard aperture?

Comment: This is probably going to be make/model specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @cabbey suggests in the comments, different manufacturers handle aperture in Live View in different ways.

Most Nikon and Pentax cameras stop down the aperture to the setting selected before entering Live View, and keep it there until the shutter is pressed regardless of the setting being changed whilst in LV.

Most Canon and Sony cameras keep the aperture wide open during Live View, then stop it down for the actual shot.

Comment: Voted this up because you got the right answer in there but your last sentence is false, at least not for cameras of recent years. Most allow the DOF button to be customized and is electrical which makes it easy for the camera to ignore!

Comment: edited - I was unaware of that :)

Comment: Sony's Pellical mirror + EVF live view is head and shoulders above anything else available so far. (I have a Nikon D700 and Sony A77 and wish the Nikon did what the Sony does in that area). The Sony allows "what you see is what you get" in eyefinder or on-LCD liveview.