# Camera hesitating or "jamming" after shooting in live view mode

Tags: nikon, nikon-d5500

Just bought a Nikon camera and started wondering why after taking a photo the camera would suddenly almost freeze or hesitate. This doesn't occur when using the viewfinder shoots like a normal camera. I have googled and found other photographers' menu settings but doesn't seem to fix the issue. Don't really want to go to a repair store if its an easy fix.

MORE DETAIL OF WHAT HAPPENS:
I take the photo which is in focus, it closes the shutter and opens. half a second goes by until another sound of a shutter opens, then it shows me the photo.

Gladly appreciate any help or tips.

Comment: I have also noticed this on a D5300 and I think it is mentioned in the For Dummies book (can't check, it's in the loft). Perhaps that what it's getting at here: https://www.dummies.com/article/home-auto-hobbies/photography/how-to-adjust-playback-timing-options-on-your-nikon-d5300-154966/

Comment: I get the same behaviour on my D5100, so most likely this is normal behaviour and nothing a repair store could fix.  However, I would still be interested in an explanation on _why_ it takes so much longer in live view (which seems counter-intuitive to me as I thought it could just leave the mirror up in this case and thus should even be faster).

Comment: I don't think the mirror has a 'rest state' of 'up' i think it's held there 'against its wishes'. It takes 10 times as long to lift it & lock it to access live view than it does to take a picture normally.

Comment: @Tetsujin What I mean is that once it is locked in the "up" position, there should be no need to bring it down between shots in live view mode. Keeping it up while it already is up may cost energy but should not cost additional time.  I would have thought that after the exposure, the camera could immediately open the shutter again to go back to live view, while in normal mode it needs to move the mirror down for the view finder.   But given the behaviour of the camera I guess there is something wrong in my assumption on how live view exactly works.

Answer (score 1):

Many Nikon bodies in the D3x00 and D5x00 series, as well as older lower tier Nikon bodies such as the D40 and D60, [use the same actuating mechanism to raise the mirror and set the lens' aperture](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/119704/15871) via the mechanical aperture linkage left over from the original F-mount system introduced around seventy years ago. In other words, the only way for these cameras to change the lens' aperture is to also cycle the mirror.